# "NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined" on Jupyter Notebook but works fine on PyCharm?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I've been doing this simple Netflix data analysis practice following the guide from a TDS post [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/exploring-netflix-data-in-python-eb03e8f3944c). I started running the codes on Jupyter Notebook but encountered `NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined` and am trying to understand why.

Out of curiosity I tried running the same codes on PyCharm and it seems to work fine, this is probably very simple but my question is, what am I missing on Jupyter and why is it working on PyCharm though? Am I missing something?

Snapshot from PyCharm:

[image: Snapshot from PyCharm]

Snapshot from Jupyter:

[image: Snapshot from Jupyter]

If it helps, I've uploaded it [here](https://github.com/supershanen/Practice), ln [14].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: As a human being reading your code, I might know what you mean by `Counter` but because you never defined it properly in your code, the computer can't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notebook cell 14:

```
def return_counter(data_frame, column_name, limit):
    from collections import Counter
print(dict(Counter(data_frame[column_name].values).most_common(limit)))
```

you import the `Counter` class in the scope of the `return_counter` function (at function scope).  By doing that, the name `Counter` is only defined for code that appears later in that function's body.  Then in that same cell, because the third line is indented at the same level as the function definition, you are attempting to instantiate the `Counter` class at global (notebook) scope. The name `Counter` is not defined at that point in the global scope, and so you get the error you're seeing.

To fix this, either move the offending line inside the function:

```
def return_counter(data_frame, column_name, limit):
    from collections import Counter
    print(dict(Counter(data_frame[column_name].values).most_common(limit)))
```

or import the `Counter` object at global scope

```
def return_counter(data_frame, column_name, limit):
    from collections import Counter
from collections import Counter
print(dict(Counter(data_frame[column_name].values).most_common(limit)))
```

As you have it, your `return_counter` function does nothing and has no reason to import the `Counter` class, so I assume it is the first option that you were going for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Yes I've gone back and it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: Do please, in the future, follow the recommendations cited in the comments.  It would generally have value for you to go back and edit your question even after getting an answer, as it will make the question more useful to others.  This question, however, is not all that valuable anyway, since it's pretty much just asking about a typo.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter much to me, but if an answer you get answers your question to your satisfaction, you should check the "check mark" button to the left of the answer to indicate this.  You can also up vote the answer with the up arrows.  You can up vote more than one answer if you found more than one helpful, but you can only mark a single answer as THE answer by checking the check mark.

Comment: Thanks everyone, appreciate all the tips, well noted on formatting - will keep this in mind. Literally just joined today, a lot to learn!

Comment: @Shanen I join to Steve's recommendation for editing your question. The fact that you got an answer already doesn't change the fact that the question is poorly formatted. Luckily, this is easily reversible by edits. Simply follow the guidelines in the comments and post the code as formatted text and not as images